# FieldPanel richtext welcome message not appearing

Tags: wagtail

I have followed the tutorial. I am not getting `<b>Welcome</b> to our new site!` message.

Basically, I am not sure where the above message is set in the model and why it is not appearing for me? I did run both `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands

```
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}
{{ page.body|richtext }}
```

[Wagtail tutorial](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/getting_started/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text "Welcome to our new site!" is not set anywhere in the model. It's just an example of some text that the user might enter when following this step of the tutorial:

> You can now edit the homepage within the Wagtail admin area (go to Explorer, Homepage, then Edit) to see the new body field. Enter some text into the body field, and publish the page.

Comment: Thanks @gasman! Is it possible to configure some other database for wagtail rather than SQLite?

Comment: Yep - PostgreSQL and MySQL are both supported, through Django's `DATABASES` setting. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases